# JHipster Microservice CORS

Tags: spring-boot, jhipster, jhipster-gateway

Is there a way to access a microservice API via the gateway without authentication? For example, if I have a public landing page that needs to read data from a microservice API. I enabled CORS and tested the API via Swagger and it works fine from within the gateway app; however, if I call the API using CURL I get an unauthorized error.

This is the CURL command I am trying to execute:

```
curl -X 'GET' \
  'http://localhost:8080/services/tajvoteservice/api/landing-page-by-organizations' \
  -H 'accept: */*' \
  -H 'X-XSRF-TOKEN: 5d3e3faf-3a3d-4905-bdea-f5ce305d3672'
```

This is the error I get:

```
{"type":"https://www.jhipster.tech/problem/problem-with-message","title":"Unauthorized","status":401,"detail":"Not Authenticated","path":"/services/tajvoteservice/api/landing-page-by-organizations","message":"error.http.401"}%
```

This is my SecurityConfiguration.java configure method:

```
    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // @formatter:off
        http
            .csrf()
            .disable()
            .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(problemSupport)
                .accessDeniedHandler(problemSupport)
        .and()
            .headers()
            .contentSecurityPolicy(jHipsterProperties.getSecurity().getContentSecurityPolicy())
        .and()
            .referrerPolicy(ReferrerPolicyHeaderWriter.ReferrerPolicy.STRICT_ORIGIN_WHEN_CROSS_ORIGIN)
        .and()
            .featurePolicy("geolocation 'none'; midi 'none'; sync-xhr 'none'; microphone 'none'; camera 'none'; magnetometer 'none'; gyroscope 'none'; fullscreen 'self'; payment 'none'")
        .and()
            .frameOptions()
            .deny()
        .and()
            .sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
        .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/api/auth-info").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/api/admin/**").hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)
            .antMatchers("/api/landing-page-by-organizations/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated()
            .antMatchers("/management/health").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/management/health/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/management/info").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/management/prometheus").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/management/**").hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)
        .and()
            .oauth2ResourceServer()
                .jwt()
                .jwtAuthenticationConverter(authenticationConverter())
                .and()
            .and()
                .oauth2Client();
        // @formatter:on
    }
```

Please advise.

Comment: Have you checked which app is triggering the http 401: gateway or service?

Comment: Thank you for your question. It is coming from the gateway. I tested this by turning off the service and running the CURL command; I still get the same error.

Comment: But the permitAll() you added to SecurityConfiguration is from the microservice, right? Have you tried doing the same in gateway? The ant matcher should be something like "/services/tajvoteservice/api/landing-page-by-organizations". Also, I don't understand why you mention CORS in your question while it is about authorization.

Comment: My CORS question is: how may I limit access to 'https://www.saathratri.com/services/tajvoteservice/api/landing-page-by-organizations' for 'GET' requests coming only from  a client hosted on www.travelodgefloridacity.com?  The solution outlined by Mr. Marziou and its implementation code shown in this StackOverflow thread open the resource 'https://www.saathratri.com/services/tajvoteservice/api/landing-page-by-organizations' to any arbitrary client connected to the Internet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you Mr. Marziou. I added to the springSecurityFilterChain method in my gateway's SecurityConfiguration.java the path matcher:

```
          .pathMatchers("/services/tajvoteservice/api/landing-page-by-organizations/**").permitAll()
```

So my gateway SecurityConfiguration's springSecurityFilterChain method is as follows:

```
    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
        // @formatter:off
        http
            .securityMatcher(new NegatedServerWebExchangeMatcher(new OrServerWebExchangeMatcher(
                pathMatchers("/app/**", "/i18n/**", "/content/**", "/swagger-ui/**", "/swagger-resources/**", "/v2/api-docs", "/v3/api-docs", "/test/**"),
                pathMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**")
            )))
            .csrf()
                .csrfTokenRepository(CookieServerCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse())
        .and()
            // See https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/5766
            .addFilterAt(new CookieCsrfFilter(), SecurityWebFiltersOrder.REACTOR_CONTEXT)
            .addFilterAt(new SpaWebFilter(), SecurityWebFiltersOrder.AUTHENTICATION)
            .exceptionHandling()
                .accessDeniedHandler(problemSupport)
                .authenticationEntryPoint(problemSupport)
        .and()
            .headers()
            .contentSecurityPolicy(jHipsterProperties.getSecurity().getContentSecurityPolicy())
            .and()
                .referrerPolicy(ReferrerPolicyServerHttpHeadersWriter.ReferrerPolicy.STRICT_ORIGIN_WHEN_CROSS_ORIGIN)
            .and()
                .featurePolicy("geolocation 'none'; midi 'none'; sync-xhr 'none'; microphone 'none'; camera 'none'; magnetometer 'none'; gyroscope 'none'; fullscreen 'self'; payment 'none'")
            .and()
                .frameOptions().disable()
        .and()
            .authorizeExchange()
            .pathMatchers("/").permitAll()
            .pathMatchers("/*.*").permitAll()
            .pathMatchers("/api/auth-info").permitAll()
            .pathMatchers("/services/tajvoteservice/api/landing-page-by-organizations/**").permitAll()
            .pathMatchers("/api/admin/**").hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)
            .pathMatchers("/api/**").authenticated()
            .pathMatchers("/services/**").authenticated()
            .pathMatchers("/management/health").permitAll()
            .pathMatchers("/management/health/**").permitAll()
            .pathMatchers("/management/info").permitAll()
            .pathMatchers("/management/prometheus").permitAll()
            .pathMatchers("/management/**").hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN);

        http.oauth2Login()
            .and()
            .oauth2ResourceServer()
                .jwt()
                .jwtAuthenticationConverter(jwtAuthenticationConverter());
        http.oauth2Client();

        // WebFlux
        http.redirectToHttps(redirect -> redirect
            .httpsRedirectWhen(e -> e.getRequest().getHeaders().containsKey("X-Forwarded-Proto")));

        // @formatter:on
        return http.build();
    }
```

Now I can run the CURL command:

```
curl -X 'GET' \
  'http://localhost:8080/services/tajvoteservice/api/landing-page-by-organizations/acfad1dd-2570-4900-a5c2-8f496f88527c'
```

And low and behold, I have JSON data with organization information!

Thanks again, Mr. Marziou!