# How to disable authenticationType in Jhipster?

Tags: jhipster, jdl

I want to have no `authenticationType`, in final microservice, how do I achieve in JDL ?

How to define such that there will no authentication ?

```json
application {
  config {
    baseName AweseomApp,
    applicationType microservice,
    packageName com.example,
    authenticationType jwt,
    prodDatabaseType postgresql
  }
  entities *
  service * with serviceClass
}

entity Cars {
   name String 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible with JDL or questions.

You must modify generated code manually in SecurityConfiguration class of microservice and gateway.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67908899/jhipster-microservice-cors) for an example.

Or you could submit a feature request similar to the "no database" option and propose to contribute it.

Comment: https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/15342 - done, thanks...